# How to XSLT using SaxonEE

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am using SaxonEE integration in the Java application to do XML transformation. I am getting the following error.

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.SecurityException: class "net.sf.saxon.Configuration$ApiProvider"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Please note that the same code is working well with the SaxonHE version. Please advise on how to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory");

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(new StringReader(XSLTString));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(MainApp.XMLDocument), new StreamResult(buffer));
```

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.SecurityException: class "net.sf.saxon.Configuration$ApiProvider"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: It always helps to state the exact version of Saxon you are trying to use. Obviously with Saxon EE the first question is whether you have a valid license and whether you have followed the steps in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/license/checklicense.html and http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/license/licensefaq.html to make sure the license is found.

Comment: My guess would be that both Saxon-HE and Saxon-EE are on the classpath, and you have loaded some classes from one and other classes from the other.